# Multiple function invoked from ng-click also using lazy evaluation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I've managed to disable `ngClick` on an element if a variable assigned to the scope (`notInProgress`) evaluates to `true` like so:

```
<a data-ng-click="notInProgress || $ctrl.setTab('renewal');</a>
```

I need to now add further function to be invoked based on the variable like so:

```html
<a data-ng-click="notInProgress || $ctrl.setTab('grantandpublishing'); 
                  notInProgress ||  activeLeft = 4;">
</a>
```

I've tried the above but it keeps returning an error:

> [Error: $parse:lval](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/lval)
>   Trying to assign a value to a non l-value

**Question**

How do I add multiple functions to `ngClick` that are disabled if `notInProgress` evaluates to `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move that code into single function like below.

```
<a data-ng-click="process($ctrl)"></a>
```

```
$scope.process = function($ctrl) {

   if (!$scope.notInProgress) {
         $ctrl.setTab('grantandpublishing');
          $scope.activeLeft = 4;
    }
}
```

So that you can call as many as functions inside that function.
Hope this helps. Let me know for any further help.

Comment: Do you know of any method for adding multiple conditional functions to `ngClick` though

Comment: actually that is not a good practice to adding multiple function calls inside html. you need to handle that in controller.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the parse error, enclose the assignment operation in bananas:

```
<a data-ng-click="notInProgress || $ctrl.setTab('grantandpublishing'); 
                  notInProgress || (activeLeft = 4)">
</a>
```